# Was the Buddha a vegetarian?

Tags: the-buddha

Was Sakyamuni Buddha a vegetarian? I've heard that he ate some pork and got poisoned by it when he died? Yet the [precepts say](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/are-all-buddhists-vegetarian) that he was vegetarian.

Which one is correct?

Comment: This question depends on which Buddhism. Chinese Mahayana is vegetarian and say the Buddha was as well and died eating Pigs delight , or rotten mushrooms.

Answer (score 4):

The Buddha was not a vegetarian.

The precepts call for no killing, but it does not say that meat cannot be eaten.

A clarification on this can be found in [MN55](https://legacy.suttacentral.net/en/mn55):

> Thus have I heard: At one time the Lord was staying at Rājagaha in
>   Jīvaka Komārabhacca's Mango Grove. Then Jīvaka Komārabhacca approached
>   the Lord; having approached, having greeted the Lord, he sat down at a
>   respectful distance. As he was sitting down at a respectful distance,
>   Jīvaka Komārabhacca spoke thus to the Lord:
>
> “This is what I have heard, revered sir: that they kill living
>   creatures on purpose for the recluse Gotama, and that the recluse
>   Gotama knowingly makes use of meat killed on purpose and specially
>   provided for him. Those who speak thus, revered sir: ‘They kill living
>   creatures on purpose for the recluse Gotama, and the recluse Gotama
>   knowingly makes use of meat killed on purpose and specially provided
>   for him’, now, are these quoting the Lord's own words, revered sir,
>   not misrepresenting the Lord with what is not fact, are they
>   explaining in conformity with Dhamma, and does no reasoned thesis give
>   occasion for contempt?”
>
> “Jīvaka, those who speak thus: ‘They kill living creatures on purpose
>   for the recluse Gotama, and the recluse Gotama knowingly makes use of
>   meat killed on purpose and specially provided for him’, these are not
>   quoting my own words, but are misrepresenting me with what is not
>   true, with what is not fact. **I, Jīvaka, say that in three cases meat
>   may not be used: if it is seen, heard, suspected (to have been killed
>   on purpose for a monk). In these three cases I, Jīvaka, say that meat
>   may not be used. But I, Jīvaka, say that in three cases meat may be
>   used: if it is not seen, heard, suspected (to have been killed on
>   purpose for a monk). In these three cases I, Jīvaka, say that meat may
>   be used.**

Regarding the Buddha being poisoned by pork, please see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/11095/471).